# Remove quotes for the specific value only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a simple loader for webpack and as a last step I need to remove the double quotes for the function. See example below:

The string I get looks like this:

```
`export default {
  mykey:
  [
    {
      valueString: "string",
      removeQuotesForValue: "() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'a' */ 'pathToA')"
    },
    {
      valueString: "someOtherString",
      removeQuotesForValue: "() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'b' */ 'pathToB')"
    }
  ]
}`
```

and I need to remove double quotes for the import function to get:

```
`export default {
  mykey:
  [
    {
      valueString: "string",
      removeQuotesForValue: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'a' */ 'pathToA')
    },
    {
      valueString: "someOtherString",
      removeQuotesForValue: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'b' */ 'pathToB')
    }
  ]
}`
```

Is this possible to achieve this with a JavaScript regex if I know that the key `removeQuotesForValue` will never change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it is strongly discouraged to work on the source code with regular expressions. However, if you can rely on the word `removeQuotesForValue`, you could opt for:

```
(removeQuotesForValue[^\n"]+)"([^\n"]+)"
```

In `JavaScript`:

```js
let source = `export default {
  mykey:
  [
    {
      valueString: "string",
      removeQuotesForValue: "() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'a' */ 'pathToA')"
    },
    {
      valueString: "someOtherString",
      removeQuotesForValue: "() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'b' */ 'pathToB')"
    }
  ]
}`;

let regex = /(removeQuotesForValue[^\n"]+)"([^\n"]+)"/g;

source = source.replace(regex, "$1$2");
console.log(source);
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ggzJEO/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this i prevent any function "**Quote**" removed by accident

```js
let removeQuotesForValue = "() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'b' */ 'pathToB')",
exportedValue;

exportedValue = removeQuotesForValue.slice(0, removeQuotesForValue.length-1);
console.log(exportedValue)
```